# Why isn't my label being displayed in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, tkinter-canvas

```
def name_label_manager(event):
    name = name_entry.get()
    label_name = Label(root, text="Name: " + name)
    label_name.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)
    label_name.delete(0, "end")

def description_label_manager(event):
    description1 = description.get()
    descrpt = Label(root, text="Description: " + description1)
    descrpt.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=W)
    descrpt.delete(0, "end")
```

i am calling them like this:

```
button_get = Button(root, text="Submit")
button_get.bind("<Button-1>", description_label_manager,name_label_manager)
button_get.grid(row=2, column=8)
```

i dont know if this i right but i am calling them with button
for some reason the desctription_label_manager label will show, but the name label wont

Comment: What do you think `label_name.delete(0, "end")` is supposed to do? The label doesn't  have a `delete` method.

Answer (score 0):

1. As Bryan Oakley pointed out, `labels` do not have a `delete method`, `Entry` `Listbox` do, but not labels
2. More so, you can think of tkinter widgets as images drawn on your screen, for these images to display text they must have variables associated with them, here we create some `StringVar()` variables and assign them to the `Entry` which you can then use the `get` method to get what is currently stored in them.
3. You can add a `command` argument to a Button to call a function, that should do in this your case.

Check out the code below to understand what I just explained above

```
import tkinter as tk
def name_label_manager(event=None):
    name = name_entry_variable.get()
    label_name = tk.Label(root, text="Name: "+name)
    label_name.grid(row=10, column=1)
    #label_name.delete(0, "end")
    description_label_manager()

def description_label_manager(event=None):
    description1 = description_entry_variable.get()
    descrpt = tk.Label(root, text="Description: "+description1)
    descrpt.grid(row=9, column=1)
    #descrpt.delete(0, "end")

root=tk.Tk()
name_entry_variable=tk.StringVar()
description_entry_variable=tk.StringVar()
name_entry=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=name_entry_variable,width=10)
name_entry.grid(row=2, column=8)
description_entry=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=description_entry_variable,width=10)
description_entry.grid(row=3, column=8)
button_get = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=name_label_manager)
#button_get.bind("<Button-1>", description_label_manager,name_label_manager) command argument of Button should do
button_get.grid(row=4, column=8)
root.mainloop()
```